# How to append 1 data frame with another based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs. I want to append one with another only if the first df is not null.
Eg:

df1

| Name | place | Animal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | China | Lion |

df2

| Name | place | Animal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Xyz | London | cheeta |
| Tom | Paris | dog |

Now I want to append df1 to df2 only if df1 is not null, how do I do that?
what I tried:

```py
for i in len(df1):
    if i > 1:
        df2.append(df1)
```

but I am getting an error. Is there a better approach?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2])`?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to specifically check if the dataframe is not null? `pd.concat` doesn't really mind empty dataframes and will run even if it is "null"

Comment: You can check for an empty dataframe with `df.empty`, but what Michael says is true, so there's no need in this case.

Comment: Yes, because i am tracking code based on daily data change and if the data is not null implies that the data is changed today and I want to include that to the final file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place whatever code you want in the if statement, I just placed a print for "DF1 is empty" as a place holder.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["ABC", "XYZ"]})

# Check if df1 is empty, if not, concatenate df1 and df2 and reset the index
if df1.empty:
    print("DF1 is empty")
else:
    df2 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True) # You can remove "ignore_index" if you don't want to reset the index
```